# RXJS flatMap to repetitive observable

Tags: rxjs, observable, ngrx, rxjs-pipeable-operators, rxjs-observables

I'm trying to implement service, which provides observable if app has connection to my server or not, so when browser online, we ping server with timer. Here is code:

```
public get $connected(): Observable<boolean> {
    return this.hasInternetConnection
               .asObservable()
               .pipe(
                 distinctUntilChanged(),
                 flatMap((connected: boolean) => {
                   if (!connected) {
                     return of(connected);
                   } else {
                     return timer(5000)
                       .pipe(
                         map(() => {
                           var success = Math.random() > 0.5;
                           console.log('PING: ' + success);
                           return success;
                         })
                       );
                   }
                 })
               );
  }
```

`hasInternetConnection` is just a BehaviorSubject bound to window `online` and `offline` events, timer emulates ping to my API server.

The issue is that my subscription `$connected` catches only first value from timer observable and then doesn't work. After `hasInternetConnection` subject changes to `false` and back to `true`, my subscription again gets first value and then nothing. Here is what I see in console:

```
PING: true
subscription tap
PING: true
PING: false
PING: true
...
```

How can I fix that? Thank you!

Comment: Example 2: timer emits after 1 second, then every 2 seconds;   

"const source = timer(1000, 2000);"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Full solution:

```
  private hasInternetConnection: BehaviorSubject<boolean> = new BehaviorSubject<boolean>(navigator.onLine);
  private connectedSubject: BehaviorSubject<boolean> = new BehaviorSubject<boolean>(true);
  private recheckConnectionSubject: Subject<void> = new Subject<void>();

  constructor(
    private readonly http: HttpClient,
  ) {
    fromEvent(window, 'online')
      .pipe(takeUntil(this.destroyed))
      .subscribe(() => {
        this.hasInternetConnection.next(true);
      });
    fromEvent(window, 'offline')
      .pipe(takeUntil(this.destroyed))
      .subscribe(() => {
        this.hasInternetConnection.next(false);
      });
    merge(
      this.hasInternetConnection,
      this.recheckConnectionSubject,
    )
      .pipe(
        mapTo(this.hasInternetConnection.value),
        switchMap((connected: boolean) => {
          if (!connected) {
            return of(connected);
          } else {
            return timer(0, 30000)
              .pipe(
                mergeMapTo(this.http.get(`${environment.apiRoot}/ping`, { responseType: 'text' })
                               .pipe(
                                 map((res) => {
                                   return true;
                                 }),
                                 catchError(() => {
                                   return of(false);
                                 })
                               )
                ),
              );
          }
        })
      )
      .subscribe(this.connectedSubject);
  }

  public get $connected(): Observable<boolean> {
    return this.connectedSubject.asObservable()
               .pipe(
                 distinctUntilChanged(),
               );
  }

  public resetTimer(): void {
      this.recheckConnectionSubject.next();
  }
```